# Why is this logo creating space between content and top of page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Thank you for taking a look at my question, I have developed a WordPress theme and added live customization to the logo using PHP (Although I think this is a HTML/CSS problem)

Here is what the logo looks like:

[image]

On top of the gavel there are some words which is creating that white banneer.

**Here's the HTML That handles the logo:**

```
  <header class="main_menu">
      <div class="container nav_wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                            <?php
               // Display the Custom Logo
               the_custom_logo();

                             if(!has_custom_logo()){
                 echo '<img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x90" class="img-responsive">';
                             }
                            ?>
            </a>
```

The the_custom_logo(); function prints out the image tag.

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this? I would ***REALLY*** appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that on top of the gavel it has words but you don't specify what the words are.

It is worth checking all your code especially in your functions the_custom_logo and hascustomlogo (not printed) for any odd echo or print statements or check your HTML for odd characters.  Sometimes echos can be used for locating or printing errors but they maybe triggered erroneously which could be causing the problem with your code.

It might help to view the source in your browser as that will tell you at which point the text is appearing in your code to help you narrow down your search.

Hope this helps